# Autoselecting the only option in a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I developed a Dropdownlist called `dropdownlist3` which has only one item in the Dropdownlist, so I want that only option to be automatically selected.  How can I do this?

My code is as follows

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (DropDownList3.Items.Count.Equals(1))
        {
            DropDownList3.Text = DropDownList3.Items[0].ToString();
        }
}
```

I tried the following code:

```
if (DropDownList3.Items.Count == 1)
    DropDownList3.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

However this didn't work.

Comment: If you only have one item in the DropDownList, then the SelectedIndex will already be zero. Have you tried just not writing any code? That should do it.

Answer (score 5):

Normally a drop down list **always** has an item selected, by default this will be the first item in the list.

If your drop down only has one item in the list, then this will be selected by default.  You can try this on a simple `.aspx` page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Test</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

What this looks like for me:

[image: test drop down]

This is a feature of the underlying html "select" control rather than the ASP.Net `DropDownList` class.

Of course this relies on `DropDownList3` being a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList` instance (i.e. actually using a select control under the covers) and there not being any JavaScript that is customising the drop down in "extreme" ways (like dynamically replacing the select control with a text box and some divs).  If this isn't the case then you will need to supply more detail.

Comment: +1 Kragen, precisely.  As stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex.aspx) "_An item is always selected in the DropDownList control._"

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectedValue:

```
DropDownList3.SelectedValue = DropDownList3.Items[0].Value;
```

Comment: I think the point to make is that there _shouldn't_ be any reason to select anything - if there's only one item, that's the selected item.